# Accessing the dataGridView values

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, forms

I'm working on a Windows Forms app.

I'm getting the table from database like this:

M_TABLE

```
a  |b  |c
---------
1  |xy |z
2  |ab |c
```

I have a dataGridView1 and I pass the table above as a datasource.

This works fine so I'm not showing the code details. But simplified it looks like this:

```
DataSet dsData = new DataSet();
dataGridView1.DataSource = dsData.Tables[0];
```

I wish to add a column with empty checkboxes to this datagridview1. I do it like this:

```
 DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn col = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
 dataGridView1.Columns.Add(col);
```

This works also fine and I can see the table with checkbox column.
I have a submit button in this form. I wish to check 2 checkboxes and submit the form. This works also fine. But after submitting I'm expecting a problem. I'm trying to loop through rows and wish to get the checked values.

```
String[] files = new String[5];
int i = 0;

foreach (DataGridViewRow item in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    if (item.Cells[3].Value is true)
        files[i] = (String)item.Cells[2].Value;
    i++;
}
```

While trying to access `item.Cells[3].Value` I'm getting an `indexofboundexception`. I can access the other values (for example row 1 :  1  |xy |z). However the added checkbox column is not accessible.

How can I access the checkbox column?

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing more code, this is only a guess, but it sounds like your grid doesn't have as many columns as you think.

Put a breakpoint just before the line that breaks, and try looking at `item.Cells` to see how many elements there are and what they contain. I suspect you'll find there are only 3 elements, which would explain your error.

If so, check your grid and make sure you have the columns you expect. If you do, post more code.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a suggestion, load the data from the database into a DataTable, add a new column of type bool and set the default value to false for allowing the user to make a selection and set the ordinal position in this case to be first column.

Here we include a primary key which is optional and set ColumnMapping to hidden so it does not appear in the DataGridView but we can access it as shown later in a button Click event. Note I don't use a DataSet but that does not matter as we still end up with a DataTable.

```
public class DataOperations
{
    private static readonly string ConnectionString =
        "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;" +
        "Initial Catalog=NorthWind2022;" +
        "Integrated Security=True;" +
        "Encrypt=False";

    public static DataTable LoadData()
    {
        var dt = new DataTable();

        using var cn = new SqlConnection { ConnectionString = ConnectionString };
        using var cmd = new SqlCommand { Connection = cn };

        cn.Open();

        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT CountryIdentifier ,[Name] FROM dbo.Countries";

        dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());

        dt.Columns["CountryIdentifier"].ColumnMapping = MappingType.Hidden;
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn()
        {
            ColumnName = "Checked", 
            DefaultValue = false, 
            DataType = typeof(bool)
        });

        dt.Columns["Checked"].SetOrdinal(0);

        return dt;

    }
}
```

To keep code clean in the form, these two language extensions are used. First to get at the DataTable, second to get checked rows.

```
internal static class DataGridViewExtensions
{
    public static DataTable DataTable(this DataGridView pDataGridView) 
        => (DataTable)pDataGridView.DataSource;

    public static List<DataRow> Checked(this DataTable pDataTable, string pColumnName) 
        => pDataTable.AsEnumerable().Where(row => row.Field<bool>(pColumnName)).ToList();
}
```

Form code where we know the column names from the original SQL SELECT statement.

```
public partial class DataGridViewForm : Form
{
    public DataGridViewForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        dataGridView1.DataSource = DataOperations.LoadData();
        dataGridView1.Columns["Checked"].HeaderText = "";
        dataGridView1.Columns["Checked"].Width = 25;
    }

    private void GetCheckedButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var checkedRows = dataGridView1
            .DataTable()
            .Checked("Checked");

        if (checkedRows.Any())
        {
            foreach (var row in checkedRows)
            {
                // logic to do your work, here I simple show how to access 
                // properties
                Debug.WriteLine($"" +
                                $"{row.Field<int>("CountryIdentifier"),-5}" +
                                $"{row.Field<string>("name")}");
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

So in closing, one must know names of columns in the SELECT statement to use later and also note rather than iterating rows in the DataGridView we iterate DataRow objects which is always better than iterating cells in a DataGridView when there is a DataSource for the DataGridView.

[image]